# Error adding field 'field_name'-'field_value' msg=For input string: \"field_Value\"

Tags: solr

We are struggling to import certain files into Solr occasionally. It seems like certain documents have weird meta data (values), not sure if it might be from eccentric word processor or something else. See two examples here:

```
Type:        Solarium\Exception\HttpException
Message:     Solr HTTP error: OK (400)
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":49},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","java.lang.NumberFormatException"],"msg":"ERROR: [doc=3932487729] Error adding field 'brightness_value'='6.18' msg=For input string: \"6.18\"","code":400}}
```

And

```
Type:        Solarium\Exception\HttpException
Severity: error --> Exception: Solr HTTP error: OK (400)
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":72},"error":{"metadata":["error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException","root-error-class","java.lang.NumberFormatException"],"msg":"ERROR: [doc=16996] Error adding field 'version'='5.3.1' msg=For input string: \"5.3.1\"","code":400}}
```

How do we prevent these issues? We are not in control of the documents, so need to fix it on the server.

Answer (score 2):

Define the field type explicitly in the schema instead of relying on Solr to create the field type for you - the first document that contains the field will make Solr guess the type of the field, and if later documents doesn't match the same, expected format, you'll get an error like this.

Always define the schema for a collection when using it in production or in an actual application - the schemaless mode is really neat for prototyping and experimenting, but in an actual application you want the types to be well defined.

Comment: Thanks! The only issue is that we receive a lot of files from external parties and get different fields all the time, so we can't plan against that unfortunately. But I guess we'll just have to catch up whenever we see an error

Comment: You can define a dynamic field as text / string (i.e. property_<name>_s or something similar), so that it accepts all formats - my guess is that you're not using these fields for calculations or range search (and therefore need them as their exact type).

Comment: No indeed. The fields that we use, are all custom fields. The meta data that comes with e.g. MS Word documents isn't used by us. Will give it a try, thanks!